# A data item was not found in the container. The container must either implement IDataItemContainer, or have a property named DataItem

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, gridview

I am trying to bind string array to grid view. While using the given below code showing the error `"A data item was not found in the container. The container must either implement IDataItemContainer, or have a property named DataItem."` Please help me to find a proper solution. Thank you.

Code:

```
protected void ddlCircle_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShadingAnalysisDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_CadEngineersTeamTableAdapter cd;
    cd = new ShadingAnalysisDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_CadEngineersTeamTableAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = cd.GetAvailableData(ddlCircle.SelectedValue); // Getting details of unassigned site

    int x, y; //z;

    DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
    dt3 = cd.GetTeam();
    y = dt3.Rows.Count;

    x = dt.Rows.Count; // counting the unassinged sites

    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
    dt2 = cd.GetAssignTeam(x);           //Getting team based on count

    string[] arr = new string[dt2.Rows.Count];
    int i = 0;
    foreach (DataRow r in dt2.Rows)
    {
        arr[i] = r["Team"].ToString(); // assigning available team to array
        i++;
    }

    string[] strArr = new string[100]; // another array to copy arr values.

    i = 0; int j = 0;
    while (j <= x)
    {
        strArr[j]=  arr[i] ; // copying the arr[] values into strArr[] based on count.
        i++;
        j++;

        if (i == 3)
        {
            i = 0;
        }
    }

    GridView2.DataSource = strArr;
    GridView2.DataBind(); // error popup here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the gridview showing strArr[j] array values

```
protected void ddlCircle_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShadingAnalysisDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_CadEngineersTeamTableAdapter cd;
    cd = new ShadingAnalysisDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_CadEngineersTeamTableAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = cd.GetAvailableData(ddlCircle.SelectedValue); // Getting details of unassigned site

    int x, y; //z;

    DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
    dt3 = cd.GetTeam();
    y = dt3.Rows.Count;

    x = dt.Rows.Count; // counting the unassinged sites

    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
    dt2 = cd.GetAssignTeam(x);           //Getting team based on count

    string[] arr = new string[dt2.Rows.Count];
    int i = 0;
    foreach (DataRow r in dt2.Rows)
    {
        arr[i] = r["Team"].ToString(); // assigning available team to array
        i++;
    }

    string[] strArr = new string[x+1]; // another array to copy arr values.

    i = 0; int j = 0;
    while (j <= x)
    {
        strArr[j]=  arr[i] ; // copying the arr[] values into strArr[] based on count.
        i++;
        j++;

        if (i == 3)
        {
            i = 0;
        }
    }

    GridView2.DataSource = strArr;
    GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Define a GridView's column such that it binds to the `Team` column of your `DataTable` and assign the `DataTable` directly to the `GridView` as `DataSource`. Then `DataBind` to the `DataTable`.

Comment: strArr[j] it contains set of values, how to bind array strArr to gridview

Comment: You cannot bind the array. You need a DataItemContainer, so don't create an array, create a DataTable for example.

Answer (score 1):

Binding Array to DataGrid is just like putting bananas in egg tray. Please you have to bind a source having structure according to datagrid. As suggested by @Konstantin D - Infragistics